# How can I run a bash script continuously every N seconds even if it fails?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to run a bash script every N seconds, where even if it fails, I want `while` loop to continue without crashing.

I am using the following solution [How to repeatedly run bash script every N seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25158585/2402577):

> while script; do sleep 10; done

It has been commented that: `This is the canonical way to repeat a command as long as it doesn't fail.`. If my script fails, I observe that the while loop is terminated.

---

Is there any way to apply `try...catch` mechansim on the script and continue the `while` loop even if the script fails?

Comment: Under the linked question there are comments containing `while true; do …` or `while :; do …`. Have you tried to test them? Have you tried to understand them?

Comment: This might help to always return true: `while script || true; do sleep 10; done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way to write an infinite `while` loop in the POSIX shell is to use the `true` command as the condition:

```
while true ; do
  script
  sleep 10
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You might try swapping the condition and action in the `while` loop, and run `script` in the background:

```
N=10
while sleep $N
do
  script &
done
```

This makes the looping mechanism not care whether `script` succeeds or fails.

This will also be somewhat easier to terminate than your example.  Just identify and kill the `sleep` process.  That will cause `sleep` to return an error code, which in turn will terminate the `while` loop.

It may also keep your script running closer to the exact interval you
request.  Your original example would run `script` every `N+X` seconds, where `N` is 10, and `X` is however long `script` takes to run.  This example should be much closer to every `N` seconds.

You should expect and prepare for the case where `script` takes more than `N` seconds to complete, and thus you may have multiple instances running concurrently.